# What's behind windows applications being launched by web launchers?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, activex

Let's say there's a web app with a login prompt. Once logged in, I can initiate a launch of an application installed on my PC.

Everything is written in JS and as far as I know, JS can't run any .exe files with parameters (obviously used to identify my account in that application). So my guess is ActiveX.

From there, two questions:

- How can I debug this launch moment from the website?
- How can I launch the given .exe with my own parameters (syntax learned from previous debug)?

Thanks !

Comment: It might be a custom protocol. Desktop applications can register a protocol with the OS, which means that whenever the user tries to go to a URL with that protocol, the OS will open the application. For example, Github Desktop uses `x-github-client://`.

Comment: @Sidney the problem is that nothing happens in chrome debugger. I'm 100% sure that the client executes something, but I can't tell what...

Comment: I don't think custom protocols will show up in the chrome debugger since Chrome hands them off to the OS to deal with. You should be able to inspect the application that you mentioned to see how it opens the desktop app.

Comment: Inspect what app? The web app or the windows app? The web app, as you said, doesn't show anything related to that call.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the web app, specifically inspecting at the code. You should be able to search for `://` which would find any URL protocol strings. You'd be looking for any URL protocol that isn't one of the usual ones (like "https://  " or "mailto://")

Comment: Is there an easy way to parse every .js loaded by the website in order to search that string?

Comment: Most editors have a "search all files" shortcut: `Ctrl + Shit + F`. The Chrome Devtools do indeed implement this shortcut.

Comment: Seems that no protocol :// is involved...

Comment: I found ActiveX lines though